# CsCart PHP Warning - Version 4.3.3

Tags: php, cs-cart

I was wondering what this error means as it spamms my error log like crazy:

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening
>   'C:/domains/XXX/wwwroot/app/addons/banners/schemas/sharing/schema.post.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='/var/www/app/lib/pear/.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /var/www/app/functions/fn.common.php on line 2106

So I decided to take a visit at the php code on line 2106 : The line of code is as follows

`$schema = $include_once ? include_once($file) : include($file);`

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

Best wishes,

Comment: Is this your custom addon or system addon? I mean banner

Answer (score 1):

Please find the `\Tygh\Bootstrap::setConfigOptions()` method at the app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php file and replace this line:

```
ini_set('include_path', $dir_root . '/app/lib/pear/' . ini_get('include_path'));
```

With this:

```
ini_set('include_path', $dir_root . '/app/lib/pear/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
```

This is a bug which was fixed in the recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm, that the file `C:/domains/XXX/wwwroot/app/addons/banners/schemas/sharing/schema.post.php` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it exists, it contains the following code:

```
<?php
/***************************************************************************
*                                                                          *
*   (c) 2004 Vladimir V. Kalynyak, Alexey V. Vinokurov, Ilya M. Shalnev    *
*                                                                          *
* This  is  commercial  software,  only  users  who have purchased a valid *
* license  and  accept  to the terms of the  License Agreement can install *
* and use this program.                                                    *
*                                                                          *
****************************************************************************
* PLEASE READ THE FULL TEXT  OF THE SOFTWARE  LICENSE   AGREEMENT  IN  THE *
* "copyright.txt" FILE PROVIDED WITH THIS DISTRIBUTION PACKAGE.            *
****************************************************************************/

$schema['banners'] = array(
        'controller' => 'banners',
        'mode' => 'update',
        'type' => 'tpl_tabs',
        'params' => array(
            'object_id' => '@banner_id',
            'object' => 'banners'
        ),
        'table' => array(
            'name' => 'banners',
            'key_field' => 'banner_id',
        ),
        'request_object' => 'banner_data',
        'have_owner' => true,
);

return $schema;
```

Comment: what about permissions for this file?